# Uncaught ReferenceError: writeData is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I try to store some objects in my database but for some reason there's a problem with my function. I get the error named in the title.

```js
//here is the Firebase config stuff 
function writeData() {
  firebase.database().ref("User").set({
    name: document.getElementById("namefield").value,
    age: document.getElementById("agefield").value
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="namefield">
<input type="text" placeholder="age" id="agefield">
<button onclick="writeData()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Remove `type="module"` or assign the function to `window`: `window.writeData = writeData` - but the better way would be to not use a global function at all but instead attach an event listener from inside the script tag as soon as everything is loaded

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot figure it out. Could you show me how to attach the event listener?

Comment: `<script>` instead of `<script type="module">`.

Comment: I cannot remove the type="module" since it's required for the firbase config

Comment: `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', writeData)` - if you have more than one button then use an ID or class instead of the element type. (But this has to be done once the DOM was rendered, you can listen on DOMContentLoaded first.)